# Remove case class field before storing to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo, playframework-2.4

I'm writing a generic update method to simplify save an case class change to mongodb. my model `T` trait has the following function:

```
  def update(id: BSONObjectID, t: T)(implicit writer: OFormat[T]): Future[WriteResult] = {
    collection.update(Json.obj("_id" -> id), t)
  }
```

when i'm calling it, it fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: reactivemongo.api.commands.UpdateWriteResult: 
DatabaseException['The _id field cannot be changed from {_id: ObjectId('4ec58120cd6cad6afc000001')} to {_id: "4ec58120cd6cad6afc000001"}.' (code = 16837)]
```

Which makes sense cause MongoDB does not allow to update the document ID even though its the same value.

I'm wondering how i would remove the _id from my case-class instance to update it in mongodb. I guess I have to tuple the instance before it is converted to BSON, but i don't know how to do that. this is my example case class:

```
case class User(
  _id: BSONObjectID,
  email: String
}
```

thanks

Comment: I suggest you to use `findAndModify` instead of update. Removing fields from case classes and build new classes using reflection doesn't look good (and not thread-safe).

Comment: You can provide a custom write, not ouputting the ID.

Comment: Mongo has the concept of `upsert` (https://mongodb.github.io/casbah/tutorial.html#update) which might come handy for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ipoteka. I would use the findAndModify command from reactive mongo.  There is an example gist [here](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/driver/samples/SimpleUseCasesSample.scala) that should help.